# Check the objects properties are null

Tags: c#

I have a class which gets a object from the external system. I want to validate my parameters are correct. It seems my object is not null even though I sent a wrong value to the service.Basically I want to check `mySalesOrderHeader` contains a valid order number or not.

For example,      `if (mySalesOrderHeader != null) { Do My Stuff}` I am checking this condition once `mySalesOrderHeader` is retrieved from the system.  Inside my `if condition[Where {Do My Stuff}]` is located, I am accessing its property and checking its existence.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySalesOrderHeader.OrderNumber)){}
```

But in here it throws a null reference exception. How can I check a property is null, if my parent object does not have the value in it.

**Note: I am using C# 3.0**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you checked how the property getter is build? Maybe it is the getter that is throwing exception not mySalesOrderHeader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Null-Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator (C#6 feature). It tests for null before performing a member access Like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySalesOrderHeader?.OrderNumber))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Akbari. but I am using c# 3.0. It seems mySalesOrderHeader is not null but I cannot access the mySalesOrderHeader.OrderNumber property.

Answer (score 3):

If the variable  mySalesOrderHeader is null, you cannot access its properties otherwise exception will be thrown.
So, you should check mySalesOrderHeader first.

```
if  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySalesOrderHeader != null ? mySalesOrderHeader.OrderNumber : null))
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tuan. It seems mySalesOrderHeader is not null but I cannot access the mySalesOrderHeader.OrderNumber property. It throws a null reference exception.

Comment: @SPKan Then you need to include the code for that property in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below snippet. Its easy and clean and would work with C# 3.0

```
if (mySalesOrderHeader != null)
{
    // are you sure you're not missing out '!' operator at string null or empty check?
    if  (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySalesOrderHeader.OrderNumber))
    {
        // logic if order number has some value
    }
}
```

Also only check for parent object once its retrieved (to me it seemed from your question that the null check is bypassed due to some reason.)